# How to set properties(attributes) of a Child class object which belong to Base Class [Inheritance]? (Pass Base's attr to Child)

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I am new to classes and OOP and was following a tutorial explaining classes and inheritance and stumbled upon something.

How can I pass the values that belong to Base class' constructor into the child class?

For example if a **BASE** class has

```
this.name=name
this .age=age
```

and the child class inherits Base class

In Base class,there are two properties

```
this.childSchoool=school
this.childfiends=friends
```

I can access the functions of Base Class using `super().func;`

if I make a child class object like

```
let childobj = new child("school_name", 6);
```

It'll initialise the child object with schoolname and age but

**HOW can I set `name` and `age` of the child class object?**

Comment: You say "In Base class,there are two properties". Do you mean the child class?

Comment: both have 2. base has name,age . Child has  School,friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, if you have a class (classB) that is inheriting from another (classA), in the classB constructor you will take in parameters for the classA constructor and pass them along.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Sub_classing_with_extends) explains this.

```
class Base {
  constructor(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  constructor(name, age, school, friends){
    super(name, age); //pass along to the Base constructor
    this.school = school;
    this.friends = friends;
  }
}

let achild = new Child('ben', 4, 'School1', 99);
```

Parameter order matters. However, you can also use named parameters:

```
let bchild = new Child(school='school2', age=9, name='chris', friends=22);
```

Or you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to pass in a map or object:

```
let amap = new Map([['name', 'sally'],['school', 'school1'],['age', 10],['friends', 9001]]);

let cchild = new Child(...amap);
```

Comment: but how would I initialise it?  I mean we'll have to do  **var c= new Child (name,age,school,friends)?**

Comment: What would be the order of params? Would it matter?

Comment: Yes, parameter order matters. You can also use parameter names, to allow you to put them in any order

Comment: Thanks a lot bud! Ps.- There are some others answers too which suggests using a function to set the name. It's quite complicating. Is there some specific case where I can't use the method you've discussed?

Comment: [Amardeep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57690566/204723) adds in [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set), which allow you to have more complex ways of updating properties, e.g. you could add in validation, say nobody over the age of 18 can be a child, so having a setter for age would allow you to check that the age isn't above 18.

Comment: Or if you have first name and surname having a getter for "name" means you could return the first and surnames concatenated. I've given the simplest example, but getters and setters are important and powerful tools

Comment: Oh! Okay. That was peculiar. But we can set and access the attributes without defining get and set. right?

Comment: Yes, essentially everything is public.

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide method to do so:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  setName = (name) => this.name = name;
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }
}

const myCat = new Cat('Tom');

console.log(myCat.name); // Logs 'Tom'

myCat.setName('Silvester');

console.log(myCat.name); // Logs 'Silvester'
```

Comment: If I have to use 'name' in my child class, why to bother all this. I mean I can just pass another parameter to base class. That's it? no?

Comment: accessing directly to properies is error prone: if the property does not exists it is simply created as new property although it's not present in original class.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I pass the values that belong to Base class' constructor into
>   the child class?

You do it through `super()` which calls the `Base` class `constructor` to initialise the properties inherited from the `Base` class.

```js
class Base{
  constructor(name, age){
   this._name = name;
   this._age = age;
  }
}
class Child extends Base{
  constructor(name, age, schoolname){
    super(name, age); //initializes the _name & _age properties
    this.schoolname = schoolname;
  }
  
  get name(){
    return this._name;
  }
  
  set name(name){
    this._name = name;
  }
  
  get age(){
  return this._age;
  }
  
  set age(age){
    this._age = age;
  }
  //getter setter for schoolname
}
const child = new Child("foo", 42, "bar");
console.log(child.name);
console.log(child.age);
child.name = "baz"
console.log(child.name);
```

In the above code the `super(name, age)` call in the `Child` class calls the `constructor(name, age)` of the `Base` class.

Now in the constructor the `this._name` & `this._age` is set, but the `this` here is actually the object of the `Child` class.

When you invoke the `new Child("foo", 42, "bar")` a new object is created, then the `this` is assigned to the new object. In the `super(name, age)` call the parameters `name` and `age` are used to initialise the `this` object so that the `child` instance will have the `_name` and `_age` properties from the `Base` class initialised with these values.

Comment: What is the difference between this method and the answers below? I have no clue about which one is better but those ones look simple. Is there any drawbacks of using those?

Comment: @Deshwal It is the same concept, where the `super()` is invoked to initialise the props from the `Base` class. I have just added some getter and setter in the `Child` class, you can ignore those.

Comment: Oh! Sorry for my lack of knowledge. It was kind of daunting. thanks for helping me out here. I'll just keep those in mind so that I can learn and use them as fast as I possibly can.